# How to use pysnmp to monitor system resources?

Tags: python, network-programming, monitoring, snmp, pysnmp

Hello I am new to python and snmp and I was wondering how can I use pysnmp to monitor system resources such as CPU usage, Memory usuage, Disk usage and NIC Load?

I am experimenting with the `cmdgen.CommandGenerator().getCmd()` but having a hard time finding the OIDs that will return me anything meaningful.

An example of what I have tried (cpu usage query):

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds =
    cmdgen.CommandGenerator().getCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('my-agent', 'public', 0),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 161)),
    '1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.1.1.13'
    )
print(varBinds)
```

output:

```
[(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1), Null(''))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a free MIB browser like mbrowse, and look at the mibs stored in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/

For specific examples ( Taken from http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/linuxoids.htm ):

Load

```
           1 minute Load: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.1
           5 minute Load: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.2
           15 minute Load: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.3
```

CPU

```
           percentage of user CPU time:    .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9.0
           raw user cpu time:                  .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.50.0
           percentages of system CPU time: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.10.0
           raw system cpu time:              .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.52.0
           percentages of idle CPU time:   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.11.0
           raw idle cpu time:                   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.53.0
           raw nice cpu time:                  .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.51.0
```

Memory Statistics

```
           Total Swap Size:                .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.3.0
           Available Swap Space:         .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.4.0
           Total RAM in machine:          .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0
           Total RAM used:                  .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0
           Total RAM Free:                   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.11.0
           Total RAM Shared:                .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.13.0
           Total RAM Buffered:              .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14.0
           Total Cached Memory:           .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0
```

Comment: Thanks Niall, I am using mbrowser and having look around. I think I worked out what my initial issue was.. It seemed like if I used the 'public' group it will only show me basic system information. If I created another community I could access more juicy info.

Comment: @Niall How you have added new community and how you got the new data..Im not able to configure it properly..